# :not(:checked) selector in safari 5 inconsistant results

Tags: jquery, html, safari

I have a bunch of checkboxes. some of them start off checked using the `checked` attribute. When you check something previously unchecked, or uncheck something previously checked, I am styling it differently so the user can see which checkboxes changed. In *Safari 5* I am using this selector:

```
[checked]:not(:checked), :not([checked]):checked{ border:1px solid red; }
```

and it works, they get a nice red border.

however, jQuery can't seem to use the same selector. when I do

```
$('[checked]:not(:checked), :not([checked]):checked').length
```

I get `0` every time, as well as

`$('[checked]:not(:checked)')` or `$(':not([checked]):checked')`. its always `0`.

I'm using the `jQuery` for a function to determines if the user has unsaved changes. Is there a workaround? It would be one thing if it failed outright all the time, but it is perplexing that it correctly styles elements with CSS, but that `jQuery` chokes. Using jQuery 1.9.1, works in all other browsers I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you cloning these checkboxes? If so, it appears that webKit breaks when cloning a checkbox with a checked property. This means that, during a clone, the checked *attribute* may not represent the *attribute* state of the original element. (I say 'may' because I didn't go down the rabbit hole to see exactly how the implementation differs when the support.appendChecked flag is set)

Here's the relevant support-detection code in jQuery.1.9.1.js

```
// #11217 - WebKit loses check when the name is after the checked attribute
input.setAttribute( "checked", "t" );
input.setAttribute( "name", "t" );

fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.appendChild( input );

// Check if a disconnected checkbox will retain its checked
// value of true after appended to the DOM (IE6/7)
support.appendChecked = input.checked;

// WebKit doesn't clone checked state correctly in fragments
support.checkClone = fragment.cloneNode( true ).cloneNode( true ).lastChild.checked;
```

Either way, I think I have a pretty straightforward workaround, albeit with a little bit of overhead:

Prepare (or have the server render) any new checkable DOM elements by giving them an attribute representing the original checked state, like "data-waschecked='true'", or use a class, like "class='waschecked'".

Here's onload code to do this:

```
$(":checked").attr("data-waschecked","true");
```

or

```
$(":checked").addClass("waschecked");
```

And css to select it:

```
[data-waschecked='true']:not(:checked), :checked:not([data-waschecked='true']) { 
    border:1px solid red; 
}
```

or

```
.waschecked:not(:checked),:checked:not(.waschecked) { 
    border:1px solid red; 
}
```

Comment: all of the originally checked elements still have the checked attribute in the DOM inspector, same for originally unchecked elements. `$('[checked]')` and `$('input[type=checkbox]:not([checked])')` both work as expected

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not expected behavior, I agree. But we're staring down into a deep deep rabbit-hole here, and unless you have a lot of extra time, I'd step over it ;) If you need to know *why* it wont work, dive into the unminified code, or post a bug report. However, if you just want **your page** to work, there are two solutions to try in my post above. DId they work for you?

Comment: the data attributes work. its just a lot of overhead... thanks for the suggestions.